# Computing Wasserstein Distance

Tags: nonparametric, algorithms, distance, computational-statistics, wasserstein

For two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, the [Wassertein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) is defined as $$W_p (\mu , \nu) = \left[ \inf\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |x-y|^p \, d\gamma (x,y) \right] ^{\frac{1}{p}} \, , $$
where $\Gamma$ is the set of all measures $\gamma $ for which $\mu$ and $\nu$ are marginals.

This is a highly non-constructive definition. So, given two sample sets, say $x_1 , \ldots , x_n$ iid from $\mu$ and $y_1 , \ldots , y_n$ from $\nu$, it is not at all obvious how to estimate $W_p (\mu , \nu)$, or even how to compute the distance between the empirical distribution.

**Question:** Given iid samples from $\mu$ and $\nu$, how does one compute the distance between the empirical distributions?

**What is known?** In the special case of $p=1$, $W_1 (\mu , \nu) = \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} |F_{\mu}(y) - F_{\nu}(y)| \, dy$, where $F_{\mu}$ and $F_{\nu}$ are the CDFs of the respective measures. The [proof](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1118101) can be easily extended to show that $W_p ^p (\mu , \nu) = \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} |F_{\mu}(y) - F_{\nu}(y)|^p \, dy$, but not to an equality.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance#Computing_the_EMD

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks,  but isn't EMD just $W_1$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it can be $W_p$, as it's a discretization of Wasserstein distance to a histogram. The distance function $d_{ij}$ is arbitrary, and can refer to any norm.

Comment: @AmirSagiv you forgot the 2 constraints that the transport function $\gamma$ should sum to $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively. The unconstrained formula you currently show is the ill-posed **Monge problem**, but if the 2 missing constraints are included instead, you would have the more popular **Kantorovich formulation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the known aspects of computation of the Wasserstein distance, as well as computation of the optimal-transport map, have been summarized in this excellent survey by Peyre and Cuturi:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567