# Is there an R or python package to calculate wasserstein metric between negative binomial distributions?

Tags: r, python, negative-binomial-distribution, distance-functions, wasserstein

As the title says I am looking for an R or python package which can calculate wasserstein distance (aka earthmovers distance between) two lists (vectors) of sampled values from a negative binomial distribution?

Relevant publication: **Barbour, A. D., Gan, H. L., & Xia, A. (2015). Stein factors for negative binomial approximation in Wasserstein distance. Bernoulli, 21(2), 1002-1013.**

Explanation of the Wasserstien distance: https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/NWD

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can use `emd()` in the [`emdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emdist/index.html) package. In Python, there is [`scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html). Related: [Computing Wasserstein Distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/381489/1352).

---

I am not *entirely* sure about `emdist`, though. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) under Examples/One-dimensional distributions, we see a simple formula we should be able to code immediately:

$$ W_1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |F_1(x)-F_2(x)|\,dx, $$

where the $F_i$ are the cumulative distribution functions of your two distributions. Since you already have samples, this can just be evaluated using the `ecdf()` function. However, the `emdist::emd()` function and this direct evaluation give me two quite different results, see below. So it would be good to check the correctness of either approach with a simpler example, because either Wikipedia, or the `emdist` package, or I have an error.

```
set.seed(1)
samples <- list(rnbinom(100,5,0.5), rnbinom(120,4,0.4))
par(mfrow=c(2,1),mai=c(.5,.5,.5,.1))
for ( ii in 1:2 ) {
    plot(as.numeric(names(table(samples[[ii]]))),table(samples[[ii]]),
        main=paste("Sample",ii),las=1,type="h",xlab="",ylab="",lwd=5,col="grey",
        xlim=range(unlist(samples)),
        ylim=range(as.numeric(unlist(sapply(samples,table),names))))
}

wasserstein <- 0
for ( xx in 0:max(unlist(samples)) ) {
    wasserstein <- wasserstein+abs(ecdf(samples[[1]])(xx)-ecdf(samples[[2]])(xx))
}
(wasserstein <- wasserstein/(max(unlist(samples))+1))
# 0.04361111    

library(emdist)
emd(cbind(1,samples[[1]]),cbind(1,samples[[2]]))
# 0.18
```

[image: histograms]